# Custom index search -Solr

Tags: content-search, solr

Any good suggestions for implementation of custom index based solr search in sitecore 9

For example any product name is clicked.the filtered result of  product name should  be populated in the home screen.the url is home.com/product name

Wil custom based search index wil b helpful for the above scenarios ? Any recommend article of implementation

Comment: Please add more details about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: It sounds like you want personalization and that’s not solr

Comment: You don't need a custom index, the sitecore index will have the data you need by default.